# In One-To-Many Bidirectional child table foreign key is not inserted(when i perform operation on parent object)

Tags: java, hibernate

It is One-To-Many Bi-Directional Relation ship .In this if i perforn operation on parent object , parent object inserted But  child object inserted without foriegn key refference(null)

/**parent class**/

```
@Entity
public class SureshHusband {
    @Id
    @Column(name="HusbandId")
    private int id;
    @Column(length=10,name="HusbandName")
    private String Name;


    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="husband")

    private Set<SureshWives> wives

// setters and getters
/**............child table .................**/

@Entity
public class SureshWives {
    @Id
    @Column(name="WifeId")

    private int wid;
    @Column(name="WifeName",length=10)
    private String WName;


     @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name="id_fk")

    private SureshHusband husband;
 // remaing setters and getters.

/** main class*/
  class Main{
public static void main(String args[]){
Configuration cfg=new Configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessioFactory factory=cfg. buildSessionFactory();
Session session=factory.openSession();  
        //parent class object 
    SureshHusband ss=new SureshHusband();

        //Child class object
        SureshWives s=new SureshWives();
        s.setWid(11);
        s.setWName("roja");

        SureshWives s2=new SureshWives();
        s2.setWid(12);
        s2.setWName("rani");

//Collecxtion type variable in parent class (Child class objects added to collection type)
  Set<SureshWives> s1=new HashSet<>();
        s1.add(s);
        s1.add(s2);
     // collection variable added to parent object
        ss.setWives(s1);
         ss.setId(102);
    ss.setName("suresh");
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
// operation perform an parent object.
       session.save(ss);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
```

/**
    Here if i perform operation on parent object the object  inserted.
 But  null value is reffered as foriegn key in child table, Why foriegn is inserted in child table .. In data base parent object is inserted But In child table Foriegn key is inserted as "null" **/
      please help me i am struglling from 1 week...

Comment: Sorry for that  i missed two lines of code  two write
 **
  ss.setId(102);
  ss.setName("suresh");**
  
  
  Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
session.save(ss);
  tx.commit();
  session.close();
   .. yes code changed .But  Parent table inserted but foriegn key is not inserted in child table....pls help me the above problem why foriegn key not inserted in child table it inserted null

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments. Please edit your post and add it there where it can be formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply. Think about this question: you save `SureshWives` via `SureshHusband`(for example `roja`):

```
SureshWives s = new SureshWives();
s.setWid(11);
s.setWName("roja");
```

which value of `s.getHusband()` do you have? Obviously `null`. So Hibernate saves that `null` into the database.

**Additional notes**

1. Don't use plural names.
2. Use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` carefully. A husband is an owner of the wifes. Right? So why the husband should be changed when you save any of the wifes? You can change the husband accidentally and save it with any wife. This is not desirable behavior. Even if you have a bidirectional relation, you should have one owner of the relation — a husband!

   @Entity
   public class SureshWive {

   ```
   @Id
   @Column(name="WifeId")
   private int wid;

   @Column(name="WifeName",length=10)
   private String WName;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="id_fk")
   private SureshHusband husband;
   ```

   }

Comment: bro i cant understand the **2nd** point what you mention above..pls elaborate that.In One -To-many Birectional if we perform any operation on parent then it will effect on child (or) If we perform any operation on child that will effect on parent (bcs  One -To-many Birectional means One -To-many  + Many-To-One).so what is the wrong in my code bro..pls explain bro

Comment: Yes Bro 2 lines of code missed in above code ..sorry for that ....@v.ladynev  yes bro i missed two lines two write
 
  ss.setId(102);
  ss.setName("suresh");
  
  
  
  
  Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
session.save(ss);
  tx.commit();
  session.close();
   .. yes code changed .But  Parent table inserted but foriegn key is not inserted in child table

Comment: @UdayReddy These two lines of the code don't change anything. The wife doesn't have a husband. You have `s.getHusband() == null` .  And I updated my answer about `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`.

Comment: Thankyou bro...now i added parent to child...s.setHusband(ss);
  s2.setHusband(ss);..its working...